# Display data based on year and week number

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am developing an application where the administrator types a `Datetime` as searching terms to match stamp dates in the database.

I need to change it so the search criteria can be based on year and week number. The scenario is the user enter year and week number in the GetWeekStamp View, which after they post redirects to Stampings view where they display the data based on the entered year and week number.

**Model 1:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Aviato.Models
{
    public partial class Stamping
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string StampingType { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Model 2:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Aviato.Models;

namespace Aviato.ViewModel
{
    public class StampingModel
    {
    public List<Stamping> Stampings { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View (GetWeekStamp):**

```
@model Aviato.Models.Stamping
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h1>Ange Datum</h1>
    <p>(ÅÅÅÅ-MM--DD)</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Timestamp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <br/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Välj" class="btn btn-default">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Tillbaka", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

**View(Stampings)**

```
@model Aviato.ViewModel.StampingModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h2>Instämplingar</h2>

    <p>Du har valt: @Model.Timestamp.Year-@Model.Timestamp.Month-@Model.Timestamp.Day</p>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stampings[0].Timestamp)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stampings[0].StampingType)
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Stampings)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Timestamp)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.StampingType)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Tillbaka", "GetWeekStamp")
    </p>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetWeekStamp()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetWeekStamp(Stamping model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Stampings", new { model.Timestamp });
}

public ActionResult Stampings(Stamping model)
{            
    var startTime = model.Timestamp;
    var endTime = model.Timestamp.AddDays(1);
    var userId = (int)Session["userId"];

    var stampings = _db.Stampings.Where(s => s.Timestamp >= startTime && s.Timestamp <= endTime)
        .Where(s => s.UserId == userId).ToList();

    var stampingModel = new StampingModel();

    stampingModel.Stampings = stampings;
    stampingModel.Timestamp = model.Timestamp;

    return View(stampingModel);
}
```

I have found this Converter class here in Stack, but I am not sure what to do with it...

**Class:**

```
public class DateConverter
{
    public static DateTime FirstDateOfWeek(int year, int weekOfYear)
    {
        var jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
        var daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Thursday - jan1.DayOfWeek;
        var firstThursday = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
        var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
        var firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstThursday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        var weekNum = weekOfYear;

        if (firstWeek <= 1)
        {
            weekNum -= 1;
        }

        var result = firstThursday.AddDays(weekNum * 7);

        return result.AddDays(-3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a model for `GetWeekStamp` view

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Aviato.Models;

namespace Aviato.ViewModel
{
    public class GetWeekStampModel
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int WeekNo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then change `GetWeekStamp` view code to this so user can enter the year and week number

```
@model Aviato.ViewModel.GetWeekStampModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h1>Year</h1>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <br />
    <br />
    <h1>Week No</h1>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WeekNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Välj" class="btn btn-default">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Tillbaka", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

then in `GetWeekStamp` controller post action method, pass the entered year and week number to `Stampings` view

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetWeekStamp(GetWeekStampModel model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Stampings", new { year = model.Year, weekNo = model.WeekNo });
}
```

The `Timestamp` property in `StampingModel` class should be removed and two new properties `Year` and `WeekNo` should be added

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Aviato.Models;

namespace Aviato.ViewModel
{
    public class StampingModel
    {
        public List<Stamping> Stampings { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int WeekNo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in `Stampings` controller get action method you can calculate the first date of the week based on `year` and `weekNo` using your `FirstDateOfWeek` method above, then use the results as the `startTime` and set `endTime` to six days after `startTime`

```
public ActionResult Stampings(int year, int weekNo)
{            
    var startTime = DateConverter.FirstDateOfWeek(year, weekNo);
    var endTime = startTime.AddDays(6);
    var userId = (int)Session["userId"];

    var stampings = _db.Stampings.Where(s => s.Timestamp >= startTime && s.Timestamp <= endTime)
        .Where(s => s.UserId == userId).ToList();

    var stampingModel = new StampingModel();

    stampingModel.Stampings = stampings;
    stampingModel.Year = year;
    stampingModel.WeekNo = weekNo;

    return View(stampingModel);
}
```

Finally change this part in `Stampings` view

```
<p>Du har valt: @Model.Timestamp.Year-@Model.Timestamp.Month-@Model.Timestamp.Day</p>
```

to this

```
<p>Du har valt: @Model.Year-@Model.WeekNo</p>
```

Comment: So by this, the user can choose a year and week and see all its stampings based on that date?

Comment: Are you saying that if the input from the user is let's say `2014` and `40`, then the view should return all records with `Timestamp` between 30 September 2014 and 5 October 2014?

Comment: That is correct, all the data which is stored for that specific date. All the columns in the database shall be displayed!

And I can actually say that it did not work...

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: And how shall I display it in the view??

I mean, I have to change it from 1 textbox to 2 to start with...

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood, in which view do you want to display records? and where does the user input the year and the week number?

Comment: The user input year and week in the GetWeekStamp View, which after they post redirects to Stampings where they display that input data...

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: So Iv'e implemented these changes. But the Method: "FirstDateOfWeek" has 1 parameter(s) bus is invoked with 2 argument(s)

Comment: You don't need to change `FirstDateOfWeek` method, use the one you already have in the question.

Answer (score 2):

you can get week number using extension method like this:

```
public static int GetWeekNumber(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    return currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dateTime, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
```

to get a year from DateTime just use:

```
var datetime = DateTime.Now; //i'm using Now, but you can use the one from Timestamp ...
var year = datetime.Year;
```